# Highlight row and column in zebra stripping table and save cell borders

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have zebra stripping table, and I already can hightlight columns and rows, but for some reason cell borders in highlighted columns are z-index below (:after)-element, even in header, where cell background is higher, but borders are still below. And so, I need to highlight row and column in zebra stripping table and save cell borders. **Without javascript**.

HTML:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="table__row table__row_header">
            <th class="table__cell table__cell_header">title 1</th>
            <th class="table__cell table__cell_header">title 2</th>
            <th class="table__cell table__cell_header">title 3</th>
            <th class="table__cell table__cell_header">title 4</th>
            <th class="table__cell table__cell_header">title 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="table__row table__row_body">
            <td class="table__cell table__cell_body">
                <span class="table__content">text 11</span>
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell table__cell_body">
                <span class="table__content">text 12</span>
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell table__cell_body">
                <div class="table__content">text 13</div>
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell table__cell_body">
                <div class="table__content">text 14</div>
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell table__cell_body">
                <span class="table__content">text 15</span>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="table__row table__row_body">
            <td class="table__cell table__cell_body">
                <span class="table__content">text 21</span>
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell table__cell_body">
                <span class="table__content">text 22</span>
            </td>
            ...
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 5px auto 5px auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: default;
}
    .table__row {
        position: relative;
    }
        .table__row_body:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: darkgrey;
        }
        .table__row_body:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }
    .table__cell {
        position: relative;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 10px solid cadetblue;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
        .table__cell_header {
            z-index: 20;
            background-color: darkslategrey;
            color: white;
        }
        .table__cell_body:hover:after {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 10;
            top: -5000px;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 10000px;
            content: "";
            background-color: lightyellow;
        }
        .table__row_body:hover .table__cell_body {
            background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
        }
    .table__content {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 20;
    }
```

[What I need (mostly in Chrome)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZv0L.png)

[Source](http://jsfiddle.net/wnfh1acx/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find solution in changing highlight color to border color and making it a little transparent:

```
background-color: rgba(95,158,160,.5);
```

instead of

```
background-color: lightyellow;
background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
```

[Result](http://jsfiddle.net/wnfh1acx/4/)